# Динамическая маршрутизация nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Использую nuxt js. Требуется прописать сложный route вида:

> localhost/page/param1/param2/param3

Где param1, param2 и param3 динамические и могут изменяться для страницы page.

Answer (score 2):

Разместите ваш vue файл страницы в дереве каталогов, соответственно маршруту, названия с _ для Nuxt означают параметр

```
pages
|--_param1
|----_param2
|------_param3
|------_param3.vue // Контроллер вашей страницы, все параметры доступны в $route
|-- Index.vue // Заглушка, можно прописывать тут Element not found
```